# Using Eclipse TableViewer, how do I navigate and edit cells with arrow keys?

Tags: eclipse, jface, tableviewer

I am using a `TableViewer` with a content provider, label provider, a `ICellModifier` and `TextCellEditors` for each column.

How can I add arrow key navigation and cell editing when the user selects the cell? I would like this to be as natural a behavior as possible.

After looking at some of the online examples, there seems to be an old way (with a `TableCursor`) and a new way (`TableCursor` does not mix with `CellEditors`??).

Currently, my `TableViewer` without a cursor will scroll in the first column only. The underlying SWT table is showing cursor as null.

Is there a good example of `TableViewer` using `CellEditors` and cell navigation via keyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a *good* example.  I use a cluster of custom code to get what I would consider to be basic table behaviors for my application working on top of `TableViewer`.  (Note that we are still targetting 3.2.2 at this point, so maybe things have gotten better or have otherwise changed.)  Some highlights:

- I do `setCellEditors()` on my `TableViewer`.
- On each `CellEditor`'s control, I establish what I consider to be an appropriate `TraverseListener`.  For example, for text cells:

  ```
  cellEditor = new TextCellEditor(table, SWT.SINGLE | getAlignment());
  cellEditor.getControl().addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
      public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
          switch (e.detail) {
          case SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT:
              // edit next column
              e.doit = true;
              e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_NONE;
              break;

          case SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS:
              // edit previous column
              e.doit = true;
              e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_NONE;
              break;

          case SWT.TRAVERSE_ARROW_NEXT:
              // Differentiate arrow right from down (they both produce the same traversal @*$&#%^)
              if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
                  // edit same column next row
                  e.doit = true;
                  e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_NONE;
              }
              break;

          case SWT.TRAVERSE_ARROW_PREVIOUS:
              // Differentiate arrow left from up (they both produce the same traversal @*$&#%^)
              if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP) {
                  // edit same column previous row
                  e.doit = true;
                  e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_NONE;
              }
              break;
          }
      }
  });
  ```

(For drop-down table cells, I catch left and right arrow instead of up and down.)

- I also add a `TraverseListener` to the `TableViewer`'s control whose job it is to begin cell editing if someone hits "return" while an entire row is selected.

  ```
  // This really just gets the traverse events for the TABLE itself.  If there is an active cell editor, this doesn't see anything.
  tableViewer.getControl().addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
      public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
          if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
              // edit first column of selected row
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Now, *how* exactly I control the editing is another story.  In my case, my whole `TableViewer` (and a representation of each column therein) is loosely wrapped up in a custom object with methods to do what the comments above say.  The implementations of those methods ultimately end up calling `tableViewer.editElement()` and then checking `tableViewer.isCellEditorActive()` to see if the cell was actually editable (so we can skip to the next editable one if not).
- I also found it useful to be able to programmatically "relinquish editing" (e.g. when tabbing out of the last cell in a row).  Unfortunately the only way I could come up with to do that is a terrible hack determined to work with my particular version by spelunking through the source for things that would produce the desired "side effects":

  ```
      private void relinquishEditing() {
          // OMG this is the only way I could find to relinquish editing without aborting.
          tableViewer.refresh("some element you don't have", false);
      }
  ```

Sorry I can't give a more complete chunk of code, but really, I'd have to release a whole mini-project of stuff, and I'm not prepared to do that now.  Hopefully this is enough of a "jumpstart" to get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what has worked for me:

```
TableViewerFocusCellManager focusCellManager = new TableViewerFocusCellManager(tableViewer,new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(tableViewer));
ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(tableViewer) {
    protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {
        return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL 
            || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION                                   
            || (event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED && event.keyCode == SWT.CR) 
            || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;
       }
};
```

I can navigate in all directions with tab while editing, and arrow around when not in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working based on this [JFace Snippet](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets#Snippet035TableCursorCellHighlighter), but I had to copy a couple of related classes also:

- org.eclipse.jface.snippets.viewers.TableCursor
- org.eclipse.jface.snippets.viewers.CursorCellHighlighter
- org.eclipse.jface.snippets.viewers.AbstractCellCursor

and I don't remember exactly where I found them. The is also a org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableCursor, but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
[Example of enabling Editor Activation on a Double Click.](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet052DouleClickCellEditor.java?view=markup)

The stuff between lines [ 110 - 128 ]  add a ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy and TableViewerEditor. In my case the I wanted a single click to begin editing so i changed line 115 from:
ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION 
to ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_CLICK_SELECTION. After adding this to my TableViewer, the tab key would go from field to field with the editor enabled.